# Github.com resolves but times out

Tags: routing

For some reason I'm unable to reach `github.com`, the connection just times out; I've been having this issue consistently for the past few days. I don't have this problem with any other website.

I'm running macOS 10.15.5.
Running `traceroute` I see the DNS resolves but then gets lost (**edit**: answers pointed out that this is expected for github):

```
$ traceroute github.com
traceroute to github.com (192.30.253.113), 64 hops max, 72 byte packets
 1  10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1)  5.508 ms  1.134 ms  1.275 ms
 2  192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)  3.066 ms  2.711 ms  2.658 ms
 3  80.10.124.196 (80.10.124.196)  69.645 ms  53.357 ms  55.386 ms
 4  10.125.222.74 (10.125.222.74)  54.702 ms  61.938 ms  38.273 ms
 5  ae44-0.niidf202.paris15earrondissement.francetelecom.net (193.252.98.246)  108.873 ms  32.476 ms  102.200 ms
 6  193.252.137.74 (193.252.137.74)  55.651 ms  82.649 ms  70.433 ms
 7  zayo-9.gw.opentransit.net (193.251.250.188)  38.020 ms  85.435 ms  91.153 ms
 8  ae27.cs1.cdg11.fr.eth.zayo.com (64.125.29.4)  168.142 ms  220.846 ms  195.284 ms
 9  ae0.cs1.cdg12.fr.eth.zayo.com (64.125.29.84)  180.439 ms  119.870 ms  108.460 ms
10  ae2.cs3.lhr11.uk.eth.zayo.com (64.125.29.25)  114.051 ms * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  209.66.120.181.ipyx-243981-004-zyo.zip.zayo.com (209.66.120.181)  112.761 ms  120.212 ms  113.661 ms
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
...
```

Using `host` confirms that DNS resolves

```
$ host github.com
github.com has address 140.82.113.4
github.com mail is handled by 5 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com.
github.com mail is handled by 5 ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com.
github.com mail is handled by 10 ALT3.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com.
github.com mail is handled by 10 ALT4.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com.
github.com mail is handled by 1 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com.
```

Running curl on the IP from `host` I can see the connection timing out trying to reach `192.30.253.113`:

```
$ curl -v --insecure -L 140.82.113.4

*   Trying 140.82.113.4...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 140.82.113.4 (140.82.113.4) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 140.82.113.4
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Content-length: 0
< Location: https://140.82.113.4/
<
* Connection #0 to host 140.82.113.4 left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://140.82.113.4/'
*   Trying 140.82.113.4...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 140.82.113.4 (140.82.113.4) port 443 (#1)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=San Francisco; O=GitHub, Inc.; CN=github.com
*  start date: May  5 00:00:00 2020 GMT
*  expire date: May 10 12:00:00 2022 GMT
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 140.82.113.4
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Content-length: 0
< Location: https://github.com/
<
* Connection #1 to host 140.82.113.4 left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://github.com/'
*   Trying 192.30.253.113...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connection failed
* connect to 192.30.253.113 port 443 failed: Operation timed out
* Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Operation timed out
* Closing connection 2
curl: (7) Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Operation timed out
* Closing connection 0
* Closing connection 1
```

At this point I'd think that the issue is on github's side, however I'm the only one having this issue among all my colleagues.

**Edit 2**
I logged in with the macOS guest account, and was able to access github.
The issue still shows on another regular user account though.
So the issue comes from some user-specific config.

I've also run `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder` and `sudo dscacheutil -flushcache`; it didn't fix the issue.

**Edit 3**
If I call `curl` without `-L` (i.e. no redirects) the request succeeds, I get the HTML for GitHub back:

```
$ curl -H "Host: github.com" --insecure -v https://140.82.118.3/
*   Trying 140.82.118.3...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 140.82.118.3 (140.82.118.3) port 443 (#0)
[...]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
[...]
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
[...]
```

Comment: As discussed below, DNS isn't your issue... For services like GitHub, it's also worth checking their [status reporting pages](https://www.githubstatus.com/) (which in this case is all green) and/or confirming the issues / addresses with others.

Comment: Trying the IP you've listed, `curl --insecure https://140.82.113.4/` is working for me...

Comment: Check if you have any web proxies set. For curl specifically, you can test with the `--noproxy` flag.

Comment: @Bob I don't have any proxies set.

Comment: @Attie with `curl --insecure https://140.82.113.4/`, does it end up connecting to that same `192.30.253.113` IP?

Comment: If you are modifying DNS on a mac, don't forget to re-initialize using `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder` I have run into that issue in the past.

Comment: @AtomicBoolean I've done that, and unfortunately it didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I was having this problem too, also for several days, and with the same ipaddress as you! Just fixed it this morning.

The way I fixed it was looking in my /etc/hosts and seeing that ip listed for github.com, and commenting out that line.

an explanation someone gave me for this

> libc (in ways that differ in different operating systems) uses /etc/hosts to override hostname lookups. this can sometimes be useful when testing things but often i just forget stuff in there...
>
> 192.30.253.113 is a github address, since they own 192.30.252.0/22. you can run whois 192.30.253.113 to confirm. it's likely that that was a valid server address for github.com at some point, but was decommissioned at a few days ago. i can't even ping it. they'll have removed it from their dns servers, but since it's hardcoded in your laptop's /etc/hosts it's oblivious to that change!

Comment: Why on Earth was github in your hosts file, rather than always being resolved by DNS?

Comment: @EricTowers looks like in 2016 during the big DYN outage (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Dyn_cyberattack) there was advice going around to add this to etc/hosts to be able to still use github  https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=12762221. I vagueellly remember doing this, but I think that was it. I bet a bunch of people are running into this now, 4 years later, heh

Comment: Yup, that's very likely what happened for me too. Next time I modify /etc/hosts I'll put a calendar reminder to set it back :)

Answer (score 6):

But your command already shows that the domain name *does* resolve (to the IP address 192.30.253.113 in line #2). If it didn't, then the trace couldn't even start at all.

The rest of your trace output has **nothing to do with resolving DNS names** – that's not what traceroute is checking at all. (The domain name is *not* re-resolved for every single packet. Once the app knows the IP address, it directly uses that address.) Instead, traceroute can show a problem with the actual network connection that follows.

Your output doesn't necessarily mean that there are problems in general – it just shows that those nodes don't feel like responding to the traceroute probes *specifically.* This is actually normal with GitHub's systems when traceroute is used in UDP mode (as they just have a firewall that blocks the UDP probes early on). You can probably switch it to ICMP probes to get slightly more accurate results:

```
sudo traceroute -I github.com
sudo traceroute -I 192.30.253.113
```

However, in your case the trace won't tell you much, as it's the final system itself, the 192.30.253.113 load-balancer, which fails to accept your HTTPS connections. But normally GitHub's ops would have quickly removed a bad address from DNS (and as your 2nd command shows, the bad address is actually no longer in DNS anymore).

In other words, the issue is that the domain resolves to the *wrong* address whenever curl or traceroute use the OS-provided name lookup facilities.

Possible options:

- You just happened to resolve the domain name when it *still had* that address, and it'll be cached by the OS for a few minutes (GitHub specifies 60s, but not all systems honor such low TTLs). Just wait a while and try again.
- You have the bad address set up as an override in /etc/hosts (which traceroute and curl honor, but the `host` or `dig` tools bypass). Check from a different device.
- Your DNS server was lying at the moment, e.g. maybe the network admin foolishly tried to override the domain name with a custom address. (Your 2nd `host` command shows good results though.) Try using a different connection such as public Wi-Fi or mobile 4G to bypass any interception.
- GitHub's nameservers were inconsistent and returned different results at different queries. (The domain is hosted by AWS *and* Dyn, it's not impossible that one update call succeeded but one failed.) Wait a while and try again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I realized that `traceroute` wasn't giving me the info I thought it was giving me.
I agree that at this point I would think that the issue is on GitHub's side, except I've been getting this issue consistently (i.e. 100% of requests fail) for the past few days.

Comment: "when traceroute is used in UDP mode (as they just have a firewall that blocks the UDP probes early on)" do you mean TCP here?

Comment: @bob - not by default... see "_List of Available Methods_" heading, [in the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/traceroute)

Comment: @Bob: No, I do mean UDP. That's the default mode for unprivileged `traceroute` on Linux and apparently [also on macOS](https://opensource.apple.com/source/network_cmds/network_cmds-77/traceroute.tproj/traceroute.c.auto.html). (At least the Linux version does indeed support TCP-probing, but that seems to give even worse results.) For comparison, Windows `tracert` always probes using ICMP.

Comment: (A more recent version of macOS traceroute manual seems to be [here](https://opensource.apple.com/source/network_cmds/network_cmds-543/traceroute.tproj/traceroute.8.auto.html).)

Comment: Ah right, forgot UDP could even work that way but of course TTL expired responses are the same in all cases.

Answer (score 4):

Github.com does resolve on your computer, as evidenced by the fact that traceroute has an IP address to work with (`192.30.253.113`). Your problem is not with DNS resolving.

In fact, the test you are trying to do has very little to do with DNS. The resolving has already been done before the test even starts. Your problem is with your packets not arriving at Github's servers.

However, the traceroute will be inconclusive for this, as it seems that some parties on the path to Github.com, have disabled traceroute in some way (see below). Github.com still works fine for me, even though I see the stars.

```
 mtak@dc4:~$ traceroute github.com
traceroute to github.com (140.82.118.4), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  l6.f2.ams4.transip.net (77.72.151.70)  16.942 ms  16.917 ms l5.f1.ams4.transip.net (77.72.151.8)  15.319 ms
 3  f1.r2.ams0.transip.net (77.72.151.124)  0.261 ms f2.r1.ams0.transip.net (77.72.151.122)  0.594 ms  0.577 ms
 4  r1-a0.e1.ams7.transip.net (157.97.168.1)  0.407 ms  0.391 ms r2-a0.e1.ams8.transip.net (157.97.168.4)  0.407 ms
 5  transip.telecity2.openpeering.nl (82.150.159.226)  0.704 ms  1.247 ms 213.198.92.21 (213.198.92.21)  2.528 ms
 6  * * xe-0-2-1.er1.ams1.nl.zip.zayo.com (64.125.12.137)  0.879 ms
 7  ae9.cs1.ams17.nl.eth.zayo.com (64.125.31.10)  6.972 ms  7.191 ms  7.150 ms
 8  ae2.cs1.fra6.de.eth.zayo.com (64.125.29.58)  7.067 ms  6.956 ms  9.627 ms
 9  ae1.mcs1.fra6.de.eth.zayo.com (64.125.29.57)  6.791 ms  6.843 ms  6.911 ms
10  82.98.193.31.IPYX-270403-001-ZYO.zip.zayo.com (82.98.193.31)  7.432 ms  7.339 ms  7.291 ms
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

At this point, I think there isn't much you can do. Resolving works, and you can get to the internet. The rest is up to other parties.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the answers given, `traceroute` can be somewhat misleading at times due to it using either ICMP or UDP packets.

You are more likely to get better info using `tcptraceroute` and target port 443. Perhaps your traceroute even supports the `-T` switch.